# Create a form saving multiple records

Tags: php, cakephp

Using CakePHP's form methods (Cake 1.3.13) I'm trying to create a form that edits and saves a great deal of records; it's really just a large table, and the user is saving a single field for each record. Cake's default form functions produce form elements that submit only one record though; when I submit the form only the last record's data is saved, since all form elements have the same name they save to only two fields in `$this->data'.

These are my form elements:

```
$this->Form->hidden('TicketNo', array('value'=>$ticket['Hauler']['TicketNo']))
$this->Form->checkbox('Paid',array('value'=>$ticket['Hauler']['Paid']))
```

This yields the following HTML, which will only save for a single record:

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[Hauler][TicketNo]" value="35498155" hiddenfield="1" id="HaulerTicketNo">
```

The format they need to be in is:

```
<input type="hidden" name="data[Hauler][id][TicketNo]" value="35498155" hiddenfield="1" id="HaulerTicketNo">
```

Where id is the primary key of the record. This way the id for the matching record is passed to the `$this->data` array and I can save all matching records if I understand correctly. I can manually construct such a form via HTML and PHP, but there must be a way for cakePHP's form methods to do this, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through your records and use this syntax:

I would not use the id as array key and instead iterate over the records:

```
$this->Form->hidden('Hauler.' . $i . '.TicketNo', array('value'=>$ticket['Hauler']['TicketNo']));
```

The resuling postdata will be an array like $data['Hauler'][0]['TicketNo']);

Put the id in a hidden field for each record and I think saveAll() should swallow it. If not loop over it and you can simply save() each record because the id is already present and you dont need to change the array structure for saving or set the id.

And you're not following the frameworks conventions by the way. 'TicketNo' should be 'ticket_no'; I strongly suggest everybody to follow the conventions.

Comment: It's external data so I have to follow their conventions. I'm trying the iterator method now though

Comment: That's worked. Oddly I'm getting `SELECT COUNT(*) AS [count] FROM [rs_Hauler] AS [Hauler] WHERE [Hauler].[id] = 225434` twice for every row that saves however; do you have any idea why that would happen with `saveAll()`?